# Не выводить одинаковые родительские рубрики!

Tags: wordpress, циклы, foreach

**Приветствую!** Товарищи программисты и коллеги веб-разработчики, помогите решить задачку, пожалуйста!
Есть вот такой код:

```
<?php
$post_type = 'my-custom-post-type';
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $arg = array('hierarchical'  => false, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC');
    $terms = get_terms("all", $arg);

    foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

       <?php
       $term = array_pop( $terms );
       $parent_term = ( $term->parent ? get_term( $term->parent, 'all' ) : $term );
       print_r($parent_term);
       if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) :
       echo '<strong>'.$parent_term->name.'</strong><br>';   
       endif; ?>

      <strong class="child_cat"><?php echo $term->name; ?></strong>

        <?php
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug,
            'include_children' => false
                    )
                )

            );
        $posts = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="child_url"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach;

endforeach; ?>
```

Который выводит:

-- Название родительской категории

--- Название дочерней категории

---- Пост из этой самой категории #1

---- Пост из этой самой категории #N

Все отлично, все работает, но не могу справится с дублями родительской категории

[image: см. скриншот]

Грубо говоря мне надо что бы раздел выводился только один раз, а точнее выводился только уникальный раздел, а если он повторяется, то выводим только первый. На скриншоте отметил повторение красной и синей стрелкой.

Comment: Нашел отличную PHP функцию `array_unique();` это похоже то что мне нужно! Например: `$org = array('1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5', '6'); $new = array_unique($org); var_dump($org);` выводит только уникальные значения из масива, без повторений! Но теперь у меня другой вопрос появился, как в моем коде создать масив который бы содержал все **Названия родительской категории** оно же **$parent_term->name** !?

Comment: Нашлось решение! Как говорится: "Все гениальное – просто." `if ($parent_term->name !=$_parent_term) echo '<strong>'.$parent_term->name.'</strong><br>';
       $_parent_term = $parent_term->name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все гениальное – просто.

```
if ($parent_term->name !=$_parent_term) echo '<strong>'.$parent_term->name.'</strong><br>'; $_parent_term = $parent_term->name;
```